# Construct intermediate proxy to change user-agent of http requests

Tags: proxy, http, user-agent

Our company blocks many http requests if they are not setting the "user-agent" to the values used by Internet Explorer or Chrome. This makes a lot of software unusable because they cannot access their data on the internet. Furthermore, checking out from svn.apache.org is impossible.

Is it possible to construct a "proxy" that just redirects http requests to another proxy, but exchanges the user agent for a fixed String?

If so, how could I start?

PS: I tried to use Fiddler to exchange the user agent, but Fiddler only sees "tunnels" which it apparently cannot manipulate.

Comment: If it is a SSL protected connection it possibly can't see what's being transferred. But as this seems to be a broken by design approach, did you talk to IT and explain why this setup doesn't work (for your needs)?

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Answer (score 1):

I agreed Seth it broken by design.

But as crazy bypass: [ZAP](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Downloads) can be used to modify HTTP Requests/Replies and make fake SSL certificates on demand.

[ZAP](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Downloads) is pentest and debug proxy.